# c# VS error list message missing the error code and file name reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

*(using VS Community 2019 v16.11 on Win 10 Pro 202H)*

I renamed a SQLite database file and updated App.config  accordingly.  I’m getting a runtime error but the message lack s the normal error code and culprit file name info:
[image]

The culprit file “BURS_Database.sqlite” is not listed in any of the solution’s projects’ references and running a Find on the entire solution returns zero hits.   MSDN’s troubleshooting guides do not provide anything useful.  I‘ve cleaned and rebuilt the solution and restarted the IDE but the error remains.

Where could the source of the error be “hiding”?

**EDIT:**
Additional, Info per request:  There are only two places in the solution (that I’m aware of) that directly “call” (if that’s actually a call) the culprit file (confirmed by a Solution wide Find): the App.Config files for the Console project and for the Winforms project:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="sqLiteDB" connectionString=
     "Data Source=D:\BURS_DataBase.sqlite;Version=3;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The connection is accessed via a dedicated class:

```
public static class ConnectionConfig
{
    public static string Connection(string id = "sqLiteDB")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

All communication  with the DB occurs via a “using” statement.

```
    using (IDbConnection dbc = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionConfig.Connection()))
```

That’s it;; the DB filename is not hard-coded anywhere else in  the solution.

HOWEVER I am unable to reproduce this error so I now suspect something in VS’s behind—the—scenes processing got hung/failed to reset.  The fix appears to be

1. Clean Solution
2. Save Solution
3. Cold boot the computer (i.e., turn power off completely)
4. Rebuild Solution

That sequence worked for me.

Comment: Search the entire solution for all occurrences of the old file name using `ctrl + shift + f`

Comment: Search out all the old names and modify them correctly.

Comment: To both comments - thx for your response but plz read question; I did the solution wide Find -- which returned zero hits -- before posting.

Comment: Have you looked for this file in this directory to see if it exists? Have you changed the attribute `copy if new` of the file? Make sure that your reference address is correct, or change the name back to see if the project can run normally. Give us more information, the current information is not enough to solve your problem.